# Set SSH connection timeout

Tags: ssh, timeout

I'm trying to cut down the time ssh is trying to open a connection to a host. If I put for example `ssh www.google.com` it takes very long until the prompt comes back.

I read about using `ssh -o ConnectTimeout=10 www.google.com` instead, but even this takes very long. Is there maybe a number of attemps I can modify to decrease the blocking time?

Comment: from ssh docs: "Use this to specifies the timeout (in seconds) used when connecting to the SSH server, instead of using the default system TCP timeout. This value is used only when the target is down or really unreachable, not when it refuses the connection."

Answer (score 95, accepted):

The problem may be that ssh is trying to connect to **all** the different IPs that `www.google.com` resolves to. For example on my machine:

```
# ssh -v -o ConnectTimeout=1 -o ConnectionAttempts=1 www.google.com
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8t 18 Jan 2012
debug1: Connecting to www.google.com [173.194.43.20] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 173.194.43.20 port 22: Connection timed out
debug1: Connecting to www.google.com [173.194.43.19] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 173.194.43.19 port 22: Connection timed out
debug1: Connecting to www.google.com [173.194.43.18] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 173.194.43.18 port 22: Connection timed out
debug1: Connecting to www.google.com [173.194.43.17] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 173.194.43.17 port 22: Connection timed out
debug1: Connecting to www.google.com [173.194.43.16] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 173.194.43.16 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host www.google.com port 22: Connection timed out
```

If I run it with a specific IP, it returns much faster.

**EDIT**: I've timed it (with `time`) and the results are:

- www.google.com - 5.086 seconds
- 173.94.43.16   - 1.054 seconds

Answer (score 7):

The ConnectTimeout option allows you to tell your ssh client how long you're willing to wait for a connection before returning an error. By setting ConnectTimeout to 1, you're effectively saying "try for at most 1 second and then fail if you haven't connected yet".

The problem is that when you connect by name, the DNS lookup can take several seconds. Connecting by IP address is much faster, and may actually work in one second or less. What sinelaw is experiencing is that every attempt to connect by DNS name is failing to occur within one second. The default setting of ConnectTimeout defers to the linux kernel connect timeout, which is usually pretty long.

Comment: It is fairly unusual for a DNS lookup to take several seconds.